# Stop UIImageView scaling up on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to stop a UIImageView from upscaling as it looks terrible. Unfortunately, I cannot control the UIImage content it is holding, so need to force it not to attempt the upscale on an iPhone 4 retina display.

What's the best advice here?

Answer (score 0):

Set its frame manually, I think.

Unless you are always using 2x images (for retina display), then you can multiply the width/height with 0.5.

Comment: Can you detect if a retina display is being used?

Comment: You can check the scale factor to see if it's a retina display, but [read this first](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html).  Checking for Retina display doesn't sound like the best solution.